# SQL join on the nearest less date

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, date-arithmetic, lateral-join

I am dealing with a problem in Postgres, where I have table ORDERS with column RECEIVED_AT and table CURRENCY_RATES with column VALID_FROM. There are similar questions on StackOverflow, but unfortunately, I am not able to utilise the answers. The task is to multiply/divide a price of order in certain currency, by RATE (column from rate CURRENCY_RATES) which is valid at the date of RECEIVED_AT.

```
--RETURNS daily currency_id, NOT currency_rates added
select  
x,
cr.currency_id
--, cr.rate
from currency_rates cr
cross join generate_series('2019-12-01'::timestamp,
               '2020-02-12'::timestamp,'1 day') as x
               --on x.x = cr.valid_from
               group by x, cr.currency_id
               order by x;
```

The best way I was able to figure it out, not further, was to join time series and currency_id for each day of time series. Now, I believe it would be possible to query it with the RATE column which is equal, or max less date than the date in orders is.

| X | Currency_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | USD |
| 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | GBP |
| 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | PLN |
| 2019-12-01 00:00:00 | EUR |
| 2019-12-02 00:00:00 | USD |
| 2019-12-02 00:00:00 | GBP |
| 2019-12-02 00:00:00 | PLN |
| 2019-12-02 00:00:00 | EUR |
| 2019-12-03 00:00:00 | USD |
| ... | ... |

Then, I will basically join it with ORDERS table on o.RECEIVED_AT = x.x and o.CURRENCY_ID = cr.CURRENCY_ID, to get cr.RATE

TABLE ORDERS

| received_at | Currency_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | EUR |
| 2020-01-01 | EUR |
| 2020-01-02 | USD |
| 2020-01-03 | USD |
| 2020-01-03 | USD |
| 2020-01-05 | USD |
| 2020-01-06 | GBP |
| ... | ... |

TABLE CURRENCY_RATES

| CURRENCY_ID | RATE | VALID_FROM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | 24.16 | 2019-12-01 |
| USD | 19.35 | 2019-12-01 |
| GBP | 27.039 | 2019-12-01 |
| PLN | 5.5 | 2019-12-01 |
| EUR | 25.32 | 2019-03-01 |
| USD | 20.34 | 2019-12-01 |
| GBP | 28.4 | 2019-03-01 |
| PLN | 5.3 | 2019-03-01 |
| ... | ... | ... |

If you can think of different approach which is more efficient, it will be pleasure for me to learn it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a row generator such as a `generate_series`. Your question reads like a typical use case for a lateral join with a row-limiting clause:

```
select o.*, cr.rate
from orders o
cross join lateral (
    select cr.*
    from currency_rates cr
    where cr.currency_id = o.currency_id and cr.valid_from <= o.received_at
    order by cr.valid_from desc 
    limit 1
) cr
```

For each order, the subquery searches the currency table for the latest row whose validity starts earlier than (or at) the order reception date.

For performance, consider an index on `currency_rates(currency_id, valid_from)` (or maybe the columns could be inverted in the index as well).

Comment: This works fine, thanks! Although it does not return the date 2020-01-01 from orders. The query makes sense to me, but this first date is just not in its result.

Comment: @RobertSoroka: that date would show up if your data is exactly as showed in the question. Maybe your order dates have a time portion, while your currency dates do not? If so, you might need to adapt the `<=` inequality.

Comment: Yes @GMB, you are right. I did not provide exact data from table ORDERS. The query works just fine! Thank you!